# How to extract 1st, 2nd and last instance of a string from a given text file based on their ids?

Tags: python

I have a text file with strings of the form below:

```
66_0M100
66_1M101
66_2M102
66_3M103
66_4M103
66_5M103
67_0M100
67_1M102
67_2M105
67_3M103
67_4M106
```

The number before "M" represents the number of instance. I have to extract the 1st, 2nd and last instances of each id (id is the first part of string, before underscore. Here it is 66 and 67). Also, if there is any id without at least 3 instances, that should be ignored.

For example, the output for ids 66 and 67 would be:

```
66_0M100 (1st instance of 66)
66_1M101 (2nd instance of 66)
66_5M103 (last instance of 66)
67_0M100 (1st instance of 67)
67_1M102 (2nd instance of 67)
67_4M106 (last instance of 67)
```

This output should be written to a new text file.

I tried the following code, it is giving me the 1st and 2nd instances but I'm not able to extract the last instance.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
for fileName in ["list.txt"]:
    with open(fileName,'r') as file1:
        for line in file1:
            col1,col2 = line.split("_")
            for i in np.unique(col1):
                id1,id2 = col2.split("M")
                if ((int(id1) == 0) or (int(id1) == 1)):
                    print(line)
```

Comment: could there be lines (identifiers) with a single instance?

Comment: sorry to mention, If there are ids without atleast 3 instances that should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex, groupby, and itemgetter can solve this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import re

pat = re.compile(r'^(\d\d)_')

def search_for_id(line):
    m = pat.search(line)
    return m.group(1) if m else ''

with open('list.txt') as f:
    which_ones = itemgetter(0, 1, -1)

    for id_key, group in groupby(f, search_for_id):
        items = list(group)
        if id_key and len(items) >= 3:
            selected_items = which_ones([x.strip() for x in items])
            print(selected_items)
```

Answer (score 1):

The crucial logic (will skip *invalid* instances and gather all the *valid* ones):

```
def ensure_instances(data_dict, id_key):
    if len(d[id_key]) < 3:
        del d[id_key]   # eliminating identifiers with less than 3 instances
    else:
        d[id_key] = d[id_key][:2] + [d[id_key][-1]]


with open('file.txt') as f:
    d = defaultdict(list)
    prev_id = None   # refers to previous identifier
    for line in f:
        id_, rest = line.split('_')
        if prev_id and id_ != prev_id:
            ensure_instances(d, prev_id)
        d[id_].append(line)
        prev_id = id_
    ensure_instances(d, id_)    # check the last identifier
    print(''.join(line for l in d.values() for line in l))
```

Sample output:

```
66_0M100
66_1M101
66_5M103
67_0M100
67_1M102
67_4M106
```

---

If you need to write output from each input file into a separate text file - open the destination file (in write mode `'w'`) along with input file, like:

```
with open('file.txt') as f, open('result.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    ...
    out_file.write(''.join(line for l in d.values() for line in l))
```

Comment: How to write this output to a text file?

Comment: You assume the input is sorted. If that's true, we don't really need a data structure at all. I was thinking defaultdict(list) as well, but I would accumulate them all, and have a separate function to retrieve the desired output from the list of instances. (Basically defer the ensure_instances check until doing the output)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thank you! I encounter an issue here. When I have the strings: 66_0M100, 66_10M101, 66_1M102, 66_2M103, the above code returns the output as: 66_0M100, 66_10M101, 66_2M103. But I expect to get 66_0M100, 66_1M102, 66_10M101. Can you please let me know how to correct this? – (Meaning the input list is not sorted according to instance number)

Comment: @SaraS, so add `sorted` call to the `else` branch within `ensure_instances` function

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That doesn't work. It is to be sorted based on the instance number not as the whole string.

Comment: @SaraS, I did not say to sort by the whole string, extract instance number and sort by it - that's obvious

Answer (score 0):

NumPy is overkill; you can do this with a simple dict.  If you need the extra formality, use a data frame with four columns, but you'll simply be replicating the dict's work.

Read a line and extract the fields you need, just as you're doing now.  The dict key is the `col1` value.  For the data processing, let me pick up the coding from that point:

```
data = {}
...
label = line.strip()
ID = label.split('_')[0]
if ID in data:
    seen = len(data[ID])
    # If we've already seen 3 instances, replace the last one;
    #   otherwise, just append the new sighting
    if seen == 3:
        data[ID][-1] = label
    else:
        data[ID].append(label)
# New ID; store the first value
else:
    data[ID] = [label]
```

You now have a dict keyed by IDs.  Each value is the first, second, and most recent sighting.  Write to the file as desired.  This *can* be done with more efficient code (smoothly handling the new-entry logic), but this will give you a good understanding of the mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)

with open('filename.txt') as file1:
    for line in file1:
        id = line[:2]  # first 2 characters
        instance = m.split('M')[0].split('_')[1]  # part between _ and M
        data[id].append(instance)

for id, strings in data.items():
    print('ID: ' + id)
    print(strings[0]) # first instance
    print(strings[1]) # second instance
    print(strings[-1]) # last instance
```

Comment: Split on the underscore. You can't assume the id is two characters long. Check len(strings). Your output doesn't match the stated output (wrong value appended)

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

for fileName in ["list.txt"]:
    with open(fileName,'r') as file1:
        for line in file1:
            id_, extra = line.split("_")
            instance_no = extra.split('M')[0]
            data[id_].append((instance_no, line.strip()))

for id_, values in data.items():
    instances_in_order = sorted(values)
    if len(values) >= 3:
        print(f'{instances_in_order[0][1]} (1st instance of {id_})')
        print(f'{instances_in_order[0][1]} (2nd instance of {id_})')
        print(f'{instances_in_order[-1][1]} (last instance of {id_})')
```

output:

```
66_0M100 (1st instance of 66)
66_0M100 (2nd instance of 66)
66_5M103 (last instance of 66)
67_0M100 (1st instance of 67)
67_0M100 (2nd instance of 67)
67_4M106 (last instance of 67)
```